# Convert jQuery statement to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the following statement from jQuery to javascript?

```
$("#tool_container .tool_wrap div").click(function () {
```

I tried:

```
document.querySelector("#tool_container .tool_wrap div").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {

document.querySelectorAll("#tool_container .tool_wrap div").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {

document.querySelector("#tool_container").querySelector(".tool_wrap").querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a list, you have to iterate over it.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#tool_container .tool_wrap div").forEach(
    div => div.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { ... })
);
```